# How to style placeholder in textarea for Explorer?

Tags: css, html, forms, internet-explorer, placeholder

I'm having trouble styling a placeholder in a textarea, for IE

I'm using this CSS (for IE):

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder, textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #00abeb;  
}
```

The input fields colors are changed. But the textarea NOT

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a workaround?

*PS: I know that placerholders does not work in all older browsers. But this is not about that*

Comment: Maybe this will help you with your problem: 

[solved placeholder issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css/2610741#2610741

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder, textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #636363;
}
```